# Linker generates undefined references derived templated class instance - code update with fix

Tags: class, templates, interface, virtual, linker-errors

I have the following abstract class -

```
#ifndef FOO_H
#define FOO_H

template <typename T>
class FOO{

 public:
  virtual void bar();

 protected:
  T foobar;


};


#endif
```

I then derive from this class -

```
#ifndef BAH_H
#define BAH_H

#include "foo.h"

template <typename T>
class BAH : public FOO<T>{

 public:
  BAH(){};
  void bar(T const &);


};


#endif


////////////////////////////////////////////////
//Class Methods
////////////////////////////////////////////////
template<class T>
void BAH<T>::bar(T const &)
{




}
```

I then create main

```
#include "bah.h"

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{

  FOO<int> *i_bah = new BAH<int>();



}
```

and on compilation % g++ main.cpp -I./

I now get -
/tmp/ccglncVU.o:(.rodata._ZTV3BAHIiE[vtable for BAH]+0x10): undefined reference to `FOO<int>::bar()'
/tmp/ccglncVU.o:(.rodata._ZTV3FOOIiE[vtable for FOO<int>]+0x10): undefined reference to`FOO::bar()'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

Comment: What did you expect? You haven't implemented the `foo::bar` method. Note that your method in the derived class has a different signature

Comment: Aaahhh... Thank you, Thank you ..... My eyes are so tired...I completely missed that...sigh ...